# What exactly is an "iteration path" in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: scrum, tfs

I'm new to TFS, and using the 2013 edition. What is meant by iteration path?

I see this when clicking on Work > Backlogs > Backlog and then it allows you to create a new User story or Bug with a dropdown for iteration path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration dropdown is meant to be used to further separate your backlog areas into iterations and releases.

[See here for more information on Areas and Iterations.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2007/01/30/my-2-cents-on-areas-and-iterations-in-team-foundation-server.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

they're your sprints, you set start and stop dates against them so that you can allocate people to tasks and see how it's all going in your sprint.